# Unable to find Signing Ceremony events in DocuSign.eSign.Model

Tags: .net, docusignapi

I'm trying to find a enum for the possible values that are returned in return URL after Signing Ceremony is completed by end user. Can some one help me find them in DocuSign.eSign.Model or a different name space?

[image: Document from https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such enumeration available in the Docusign [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

Your app will have to create the enumeration if needed. Here are the possible values. Avaliable [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/#definitions--recipientViewRequest) (expand the recipientViewRequest)

- **access_code_failed** : Recipient used incorrect access code.
- **cancel** : Recipient canceled the signing operation, possibly by using the Finish Later option.
- **decline** : Recipient declined to sign.
- **exception** : A system error occurred during signing.
- **fax_pending** :Recipient has a fax pending.
- **id_check_failed** : Recipient failed an ID check.
- **session_timeout** : The session timed out. An account can control this timeout using the Signer Session Timeout option.
- **signing_complete** : Recipient completed the signing ceremony.
- **ttl_expired** : The Time To Live token for the envelope has expired. After being successfully invoked, these tokens expire after 5 minutes or if the envelope is voided.
- **viewing_complete** : Recipient completds viewing an envelope that is in a read-only/terminal state such as completed, declined, or voided.

Comment: What if this list gets updated on DocuSign API? Please Consider adding a enum for this in your future release.

Comment: Sure I will pass this info to the SDK development team. Meanwhile since the SDK code is open source, you can fork it and submit a pull request with your changes.

Comment: Opened a [issue](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/127) for your request. Feel free to add more info there.

Comment: Thank you Reddy brothers, this Q&A really helped.